# Terminal not returning to normal after Bash Script

Tags: bash

I'd like the terminal to return to normal after the bash script has been executed.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -ne "\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00" |nc 192.168.0.119 502 > /home/pi/mb.txt

exit 0
```

Currently, the script runs as expected and the output goes to its destination, but the terminal then hangs after running `./script`, waiting for me to hit CTRL-C. I'd like the terminal to return to normal right after the script has run.

Comment: you are spawning a new xterm (i guess?) in which you are running nc ?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Remove the `exit 0` line - it's not needed (and bad practice, but that's another story). Is this an issue specific to `nc`?

Comment: What would cause the nc connection to end and reach the `exit 0`? I think nothing. As @wjandrea mentioned it isn't needed. You could just add `-q` or `-c` to end it.

Answer (score 2):

```
nc -N 192.168.0.119 502
```

From the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html):

> -N
>   shutdown(2) the network socket after EOF on the input.  Some servers require this to finish their work.

Note that this may not be available in some versions.